# Minecraft Flood fill

Tags: c, minecraft, flood-fill

I am trying to calculate minecraft's light values, but the algorithm I use is very slow.

What is a better way to calculate the lighting array?

The code looks like this:

```
struct chunk_data {
    char light[16*16*256];
};

int j;

void fill(chunk_data* c, int i, int l) {
        ++j;
        if(c->light[i] > l)
                return;
        c->light[i] = l;
        if(!--l)
                return;
        if((i&0x0F) != 0x0F)
                fill(c, i + 0x01, l);
        if((i&0x0F) != 0x00)
                fill(c, i - 0x01, l);
        if((i&0xF0) != 0xF0)
                fill(c, i + 0x10, l);
        if((i&0xF0) != 0x00)
                fill(c, i - 0x10, l);
        if((i&0xFF00) != 0x0000)
                fill(c, i - 0x0100, l);
        if((i&0xFF00) != 0xFF00)
                fill(c, i + 0x0100, l);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I move the check before I call into recursion, then number of stack pushes is reduced.
This reduces the running time from 250ms to 23us.

Improved code:

```
void fill(chunk_data* c, int i, int l) {
        c->light[i] = l;
        if(!--l)
                return;
        if((i&0x0F) != 0x0F && c->light[i + 0x01] < l)
                fill(c, i + 0x01, l);
        if((i&0x0F) != 0x00 && c->light[i - 0x01] < l)
                fill(c, i - 0x01, l);
        if((i&0xF0) != 0xF0 && c->light[i + 0x10] < l)
                fill(c, i + 0x10, l);
        if((i&0xF0) != 0x00 && c->light[i - 0x10] < l)
                fill(c, i - 0x10, l);
        if((i&0xFF00) != 0x0000 && c->light[i - 0x0100] < l)
                fill(c, i - 0x0100, l);
        if((i&0xFF00) != 0xFF00 && c->light[i + 0x0100] < l)
                fill(c, i + 0x0100, l);
}
```